# jqgrid not displaying/populating the table with "data" element data

Tags: jqgrid

The run time data "queryData" is exactly same as sample data "myData" , "queryData" is runtime data coming from ajax, but the table is not populated with the data. If i replace the "queryData" with "myData" in the data element of the jqGrid "data: queryData", table is populating. I am not getting any error with "queryData" and table is not populated.

```
function populateTable(dataToPopulate){ 
    var queryData = JSON.stringify(dataToPopulate);
    alert('--query data is:'+queryData);
    $("#searchResultsGrid").jqGrid({         
         data: queryData,
         datatype: 'local',                     
         colNames: ['Claim Number', 'Injury date', 'Last Name', 'First name', 'MI', 'SSN'],
         colModel: [{name: 'claimNumber', index: 'claimNumber', width: 110, align: 'left',sortable:true},    {name: 'doi', index: 'doi', width: 130, sortable:true},   {name: 'lastName', index: 'lastName', width: 120, sortable:true},   {name: 'firstName', index: 'firstName', width: 65, sortable:true}, {name: 'miName', index: 'miName', width: 60, align: 'center', sortable:true},{name: 'ssn', index: 'ssn', width: 95, align: 'center', sortable:true}   ],
         caption: 'Search Results',
         height: '100%',
         width: '100%',
         rownumbers: true,
         sortname : 'doi',
         sortorder : 'desc',
         viewrecords : true,
         autowidth: true,
         hidegrid: false
    });     
}
//sample local data
var myData = [  {"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"null", "ssn":"123-456-7890"},{"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"X", "ssn":"123-456-7890"},   {"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"X", "ssn":"123-456-7890"} ];
```

Answer (score 0):

There was some issues in your code.

change `data: queryData`, to `datastr:  queryData`,

change `datatype: 'local'`, to `datatype: "jsonstring"`,

add  `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },` to your grid option

json string should be in the given below format

```
var myData = {
                "page": "1",
                "records": "2",
                "rows": [ 
                         {"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"null", "ssn":"123-456-7890"},
                         {"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"X", "ssn":"123-456-7890"},   
                         {"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"X", "ssn":"123-456-7890"} ]};
```

Below given is working version of your code

```
function populateTable(queryData){ 
            var queryData = JSON.stringify(queryData);
            alert('--query data is:'+queryData);
            $("#searchResultsGrid").jqGrid({         
                datastr:  queryData,
               //  pager:'#searchResultsGridPagingTool',
                 datatype: "jsonstring",               
                 colNames: ['Claim Number', 'Injury date', 'Last Name', 'First name', 'MI', 'SSN'],
                 colModel: [{name: 'claimNumber', index: 'claimNumber', width: 110, align: 'left',sortable:true},
                            {name: 'doi', index: 'doi', width: 130, sortable:true},   
                            {name: 'lastName', index: 'lastName', width: 120, sortable:true},   
                            {name: 'firstName', index: 'firstName', width: 65, sortable:true}, 
                            {name: 'miName', index: 'miName', width: 60, align: 'center', sortable:true},
                            {name: 'ssn', index: 'ssn', width: 95, align: 'center', sortable:true}   ],
                 caption: 'Search Results',
                 height: '100%',
                 width: '100%',
                 rownumbers: true,
                 jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                 sortname : 'doi',
                 sortorder : 'desc',
                 viewrecords : true,
                 autowidth: true,
                 hidegrid: false
            });     
        }
        //sample local data
        var myData = {
                "page": "1",
                "records": "2",
                "rows": [ 
                         {"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"null", "ssn":"123-456-7890"},
                         {"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"X", "ssn":"123-456-7890"},   
                         {"claimNumber":"NF873673", "doi":"12/12/2012", "lastName":"Doe", "firstName":"John", "miName":"X", "ssn":"123-456-7890"} ]};

        populateTable(myData);
```